# Exception while installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, opensuse

```
I am getting following exception while installing rails in Opensuse.
Version of Ruby is ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xslt/test_custom_functions.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test/xslt/test_exception_handling.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/test_all
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
current directory: /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby.ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20160625-7943-34np6o.rb extconf.rb
Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby.ruby2.1
        --help
        --clean
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
        from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
        from extconf.rb:162:in `block in add_cflags'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:621:in `with_cflags'
        from extconf.rb:161:in `add_cflags'
        from extconf.rb:414:in `<main>'
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
```

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Content of mkmf.log is follows:

```
gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include /ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I.    -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib64 -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby2.1  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc "
checked program was:



/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2:
 3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 4: {
 5:   return 0;
 6: }
 /* end */
```

Comment: The nokogiri gem is famous for being hard to install at times. They provide useful troubleshooting tips on their homepage nokogiri.org. Did you check these? What did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried a number of options like installing ruby-devel, libxml2-devel, libxslt-devel etc. I also specified option --use-system-libraries while installing nokogiri. I also updated the patch. A lot of people(Many stack Overflow questions) have faced problems while installing nokogiri, but none worked for me.

Comment: I got it installed using software management. But still if anyone has any clue, please post the answer, other people might face the issue.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/06/building-native-extensions-for-ruby-gems.html

Comment: Thanks Ed. I was facing similar issues while installing other Ruby gems. I had them resolved after compiling required dev tools.